# Any good alternatives to Inverse Symbolic Calculator?

Tags: reference-request, math-software, advice, online-resources

Inverse Symbolic Calculator (ISC for short) is down indefinitely (and has been down for many years). Wolfram alpha can give answers in simple cases, but from my experience ISC was much more useful. What should I do now?

What would you use instead of this resource now?

Comment: The ["original ISC"](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html) (as linked from the ISC page) still works.

Comment: Use full *Mathematica*.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork. I am not a Mathematica user but, when I go to university, I can use it. Could you show me the syntax to be used for this purpose ? Thanks.

Comment: Possibly RIES code is the best option now: https://mrob.com/pub/ries/

Comment: @David Late by half a year, but I'm not sure that has anything to do with the question.

Comment: @YiFan:  Huh?  You asked for "inverse symbolic calculator" and I referenced what, to the best of my knowledge, is the most sophisticated and useful software for calculating an inverse function.  If that isn't what you're asking, then I think everyone here is off the mark.

Comment: @David Firstly, I'm not the OP. Secondly, the ISC has nothing at all to do with inverse functions; what it does is given a numerical value, tries to find its exact form. So putting in 3.1415936535 will give you the output $\pi$.

Answer (score 4):

This is mentioned by Gottfried Helms in a comment, but it really deserves to be a full answer: https://mrob.com/pub/ries/

You'll have to compile and run it yourself (I could swear there used to be a web UI years ago), but it's exactly what you're looking for. The results are also better (i.e. simpler and more plausible) than those provided by ISC in my experience. They're ranked by "complexity", which makes finding the symbolic expression you're looking for a lot simpler.

Answer (score 3):

The site is down indefinitely, however, it is still accessible at the [original site](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html) (via the Wayback Machine).