# Is it possible to always convert a decimal to exact value?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was just wondering if you could backtrack any decimal to an exact value representation. Like for example, if I ask to find the exact value of 0.1522098214357..., would it even be possible to find that its exact value is the 5th root of 116 all divided by 17, or can it only be done with rational numbers?

Comment: Related: [Any good alternatives to Inverse Symbolic Calculator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251082/any-good-alternatives-to-inverse-symbolic-calculator)

Comment: In order to get some precise answers, you have to define carefully what you mean by "exact value representation". For example, if you mean by that that you represent a "decimal" as being one of the roots of a polynomial with rational coefficients, then the answer is no, in the sense that you cannot always do that. Indeed, counterexamples do exist. They are called transcendental numbers and include for example $\pi$ and $e$. By the way, proving that $\pi$ and $e$ are transcendental is highly non-trivial.

Comment: While I generally dislike the ultra-finitist and intuitionist viewpoints, there are some good points to be had here.  If you were to be able to unambiguously select a number like $0.1522098\dots$ then you would need a way to be unambiguous about it.  You would need to know something about that number which sets it apart from other numbers.  Typically, that knowledge will be exactly the knowledge you were hoping for... a representation.  Otherwise, if you can not be unambiguous then you could simply assume all digits which follow where you left off are zeroes and assume the number is rational.

Comment: That number you've got there? What's its 2,345th digit?

Comment: Any decimal you can write - yes. After all you have to stop writing some time. Any repeating or terminating decimal - yes. These are all rational numbers. In general, no. And there are more real numbers than descriptions.